# 'SSLClose' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - No longer supported. Use Network.framework

Tags: objective-c

I am using an Objective-C file in my Swift app. How do I import Network in a .m file?

> Warning: 'SSLClose' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - No longer supported. Use Network.framework.

Says: #import "Network.h" not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing a system header file in Objective-C, it would look something like:

```
#import <Network/Network.h>
```

It's easier to rely in code completion in Xcode. Type the `#import` and then pick the option with the `< >`. Then start typing `Network`.